# Как сделать имитацию прокручивания колесика мыши в стороннем приложении?

Tags: c#, .net

Как можно сделать имитацию прокручивания колесика мыши?
  c#. в стороннем приложении

Comment: Посылать сообщение WM_MOUSEWHEEL с помощью WinAPI-функции SendMessage или PostMessage.

Answer (score 6):

Заставить это работать оказалось не так уж и просто. Дело в том, что в Windows 10 событие прокручивание колёсика доставляется окну под мышиным курсором, а не окну с фокусом, и значит, недостаточно дать окну фокус, нужно ещё и перенести мышь внутрь него. Вооружимся P/Invoke, так как нужных функций во фреймфорке нет.

Итак, определения функций и структур данных:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In] INPUT[] pInputs,
    int cbSize);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)] [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

enum INPUT_TYPE : uint
{
    INPUT_MOUSE = 0,
    INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1,
    INPUT_HARDWARE = 2
}

struct INPUT
{
    public INPUT_TYPE type;
    public MOUSEINPUT mi;
}

struct MOUSEINPUT
{
    public int dx;
    public int dy;
    public int mouseData;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

const int MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_HWHEEL = 0x01000;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}

const int WHEEL_DELTA = 120;
```

Теперь со всем этим хозяйством на борту попытаемся взлететь:

```
static void MoveWheel(IntPtr hWnd, int step)
{
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd); // окно на передний план
    Thread.Sleep(1000);        // подождём, чтобы оно успело показаться

    if (!GetWindowRect(hWnd, out RECT rect)) // получаем позицию
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

    int x = (rect.Left + rect.Right)/2, y = (rect.Top + rect.Bottom)/2;

    if (!SetCursorPos(x, y)) // переносим мышь с центр окна
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

    var inputs = new[]
    {
        new INPUT()
        {
            type = INPUT_TYPE.INPUT_MOUSE,
            mi = new MOUSEINPUT()
            {
                dx = 0,
                dy = 0,
                mouseData = step * WHEEL_DELTA,
                dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE,
                time = 0, // сгенерированное системой время
                dwExtraInfo = (IntPtr)0
            }
        }
    };
    var result = SendInput((uint)inputs.Length, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(inputs[0]));
    if (result == 0)
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

Вам придётся найти хэндл вашего окна (например, используя `FindWindow` из `user32.dll`) самостоятельно.

Дополнительное чтение по теме:

- [Why are mouse wheel messages delivered to the focus window instead of the window under the mouse?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160420-00/?p=93325)
- [SendInput function on docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)
- [P/Invoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/)
- [How to: Simulate Mouse and Keyboard Events in Code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-simulate-mouse-and-keyboard-events-in-code)
- [how to programatically mouse move,click,right click and keypress, etc. in winform and wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5094398/276994)
- [SendInput doesn't perform click mouse button unless I move cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8021954/276994)